# Script para hacer deploys

Tags: git, github, git-push, gitlab, git-commit

Tengo un proyecto en local con **laravel** donde uso **git-flow** por lo que tengo las ramas develop y master en LOCAL más las features que voy haciendo.

Cada vez que hago una feature la integro en develop, luego la integro en master y finalmente hago el PUSH a la rama remoto, por lo que tengo sincronizado el código local con el repositorio.

Una vez en la parte del servidor de momento hago los "deploys" a mano, tengo que mirar si implementamos rundeck o directament desde gitlab con cd/ci, pero de mientras he hecho este script sacando la base de internet.

El script basicamente se posiciona en el directorio del proyecto, hace un git pull de master , composer para instalar dependencias y comandos diversos de laravel para borrar cachés.

```
# Change to the project directory
cd /var/www/html/cars_backend

# Turn on maintenance mode
php artisan down

# Pull the latest changes from the git repository
# git reset --hard
# git clean -df
git pull origin master

# Install/update composer dependecies
composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader --no-dev

# Run database migrations
# php artisan migrate --force
php artisan migrate
# Clear caches
php artisan cache:clear


# Clear and cache routes and cache config
php artisan route:clear
php artisan route:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache

# Install node modules
npm install

# Build assets using Laravel Mix
npm run production

# Turn off maintenance mode
php artisan up
```

El script hace todo lo que debe hacer, se descarga los ficheros..lanza composer para instalar las dependencias , etc...

El problema esta que si hay dependencias,se baja los ficheros y los marca sin "estado" en git, por lo que cuando intento hacer otro deploy esos archivos quedan pendientes de hacer algo y no me deja hacer el git pull.

Cual seria la mejor opción, hacer un paso previa de bajar el código en una carpeta temporal y de allí lanzar un rsync a la carpeta?

O  hacer un git clean -df

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Dependencias de que tipo? Node o php? Tienes esas carpetas y archivos `.lock` en `.gitignore`?

Comment: Si dependencias de node y php.